# How to override Go environment variables with Helm

Tags: go, environment-variables, kubernetes-helm

How do I override environment variables in a .env file for Go with Helm?

With C# I do the following:

In `appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "Animals":{
        "Pig": "Squeek"
    },
}
```

In `values.yaml`:

```
animals:
  pig: "Oink"
```

In `configmap.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: animal-configmap
pig: {{ .Values.animals.pig }}
```

And finally in `deployment.yaml`:

```
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      ...
      containers:
          ...
          env:
            - name: Animals__Pig
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: animal-configmap  
                  key: pig
```

Not the double `__`.
How would one go about updating an environment value for Go?

Here is the Go `.env` file example:

```
PIG=SQUEEK
```

Comment: What Go code is reading the environment variable?  (Are you using [`os.Getenv()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Getenv) or something else?)  If the environment variable is named `PIG` then the Kubernetes manifest should say `name: PIG` there.

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes os.Getenv(). Post this comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Go code is retrieving an ordinary environment variable

```golang
pig := os.Getenv("PIG")
```

then the Kubernetes manifest should use that name as the environment variable `name:`

```yaml
env:
  - name: PIG
    valueFrom: {...}
```

The double-underscore doesn't have any special meaning in Unix environment variables or the Kubernetes manifest, in your initial example it looks like the way the C# framework separates components when it maps environment variables to application properties.  If you're using environment variables directly you don't need to do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `"github.com/joho/godotenv"` package to read `.env` files. Since you don't want to mix up existing environment variables with those from the `.env` file, you can create a map and set the vars to it.

If you have a `.env` file like this:

```
HELLO=word
```

You can read it like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func main() {
    var envs map[string]string
    envs, err := godotenv.Read(".env")

    if err != nil {
        panic("Error loading .env file")
    }

    name := envs["HELLO"]

    fmt.Println(name)
}
```

If you set a var env, you can still access the value defined on the file:

```bash
$ HELLO=ping go run main.go

world
```

Then you access the file vars from the `envs` var.

Comment: Thats what I am doing. It does not answer how to override the env var from helm